# kangaroo maths competition

Tags: combinatorics, integers

How many three-digit positive integers $ABC$ exist, such that $(A + B)^c$ is a three-digit integer and an integer power of $2$?
Note: An integer power of $2$ is a number in the form $2^k$
, where $k$ is an integer.

(A) $15$

(B) $16$

(C) $18$

(D) $20$

(E) $21$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: 2 to the power of k that gives 3 digits are 128 256 512

Comment: correct so far!

Comment: 2 to the power of k that gives 3 digits are 128 256 512 (a+b)^c  so √256=16 4√256=4 8√256=2 7√128=2 3√512=8 4√512=2   (1+15)^2  (10+6)^2 (8+8)^2 (7+9)^2 (1+3)^4 (2+2)^4 (1+1)^8(1+1)^7 (4+4)^3 (5+3)^3 (6+2)^3 (7+1)^3 (1+1)^9 13 three digit integers

Comment: please try to add dollar signs around expressions so it will be a lot readable

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

You basically have to find the number of solutions to the following equations

$$
(A+B)^C=2^7\qquad (A+B)^C=2^8\qquad (A+B)^C=2^9, \quad A,B,C\in\{0,1,2,...,9\}
$$

Which directly gives some clues about what $C$ could be. Can $A$ be equal to zero?

Comment: but the internet say 0 is neither positive or negative integer

Comment: but $A,B,C$ here are *digits*

Comment: but i get 19 solutions for that

Comment: You should add these to your question so we can look at it together

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete list of $21$ solutions.

- $2^7=128:$

  - $2^7=(1+1)^7\implies ABC=117$
  - $2^7=(2+0)^7\implies ABC=207$
- $2^8=4^4=16^2=256:$

  - $2^8=(1+1)^8\implies ABC=118$
  - $2^8=(2+0)^8\implies ABC=208$
  - $4^4=(1+3)^4\implies ABC=134$
  - $4^4=(2+2)^4\implies ABC=224$
  - $4^4=(3+1)^4\implies ABC=314$
  - $4^4=(4+0)^4\implies ABC=404$
  - $16^2=(7+9)^2\implies ABC=792$
  - $16^2=(8+8)^2\implies ABC=882$
  - $16^2=(9+7)^2\implies ABC=972$
- $2^9=8^3=512:$

  - $2^9=(1+1)^9\implies ABC=119$
  - $2^9=(2+0)^9\implies ABC=209$
  - $8^3=(1+7)^3\implies ABC=173$
  - $8^3=(2+6)^3\implies ABC=263$
  - $8^3=(3+5)^3\implies ABC=353$
  - $8^3=(4+4)^3\implies ABC=443$
  - $8^3=(5+3)^3\implies ABC=533$
  - $8^3=(6+2)^3\implies ABC=623$
  - $8^3=(7+1)^3\implies ABC=713$
  - $8^3=(8+0)^3\implies ABC=803$

Comment: this was educational...